# How to limit max bandwidth per IP/MAC address

Tags: wireless-router, download, bandwidth

I have a client who would like to offer free bandwidth to his clientèle but limit the amount of downloaded bandwidth by either MAC address or IP address on a given day. Believe it or not, bandwidth is still very expensive in South Africa, hence the limit needed to be placed on clients.

Basically, we would like to set up a Wireless DHCP router to which anyone can connect with the right password. The person would then be able to connect but will only be allowed to connect and download a maximum of say 20Mb.

I've read a fair amount on QoS but nothing as specific as what I am looking for.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

The [Gargoyle](http://www.gargoyle-router.com/index.php) router firmware looks like it may do what you're looking for.  Check their [list](http://www.gargoyle-router.com/wiki/doku.php?id=supported_routers_-_tested_routers) of supported routers though.

I don't have any personal experience with it, but this [screenshot](http://www.gargoyle-router.com/wiki/lib/exe/detail.php?id=screenshots&media=screenshots:14_quotas.jpg) looks like configuration settings for exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also, [this](http://superuser.com/q/353343/128794) SU question may be pertinent.

Comment: +1 for including all those links and not making SixFootJames google anything.